# Slide Menu and ActionBar with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I'm trying to make phonegap project. I'm using html5, css  and javascript you know.
On this project, i want to make a my interface like google plays or twitter's new interface.

"When i swipe left or right, my menu will change and also my navigation will change."
like these pictures to you to remember;

- http://mobilesyrup.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Screenshot_2012-03-16-08-39-13-e1331912372399.jpg
- http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-gH_0tHDveKc/UVtxpipM00I/AAAAAAAAAiY/5P2vhxa3KtQ/s1600/android_new+design.png

i found some jsfiddle demos on the internet but, the both of them are not together on the samples.
For example ; 
This only show swiping right and left;

```
 - http://jsfiddle.net/QjUMh/
```

This one is by clicking from top;

```
 - `http://jsfiddle.net/XJVYj/`
```

Please help me about this swipe, slide or whatever you call thing. I want to understand and use it on my project as soon as possible.

Thank you !

Comment: What is it about the code samples you have found that you do not understand? Remember SO is not a hire-a-coder site.

Comment: There is not a code sample i've found that i do not understand. I just asking is it possible to slide and swipe can be combined ?

Comment: @KuthayGumus did you finish it? i have same question.

Comment: @AnhTú the most optimal solution is with iscroll. Try to use it. http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4